# Find value in vector and return reference to value

Tags: c++

I'm using this function to find value in `vector`.

```
void program_data::find_curlAccountdata(int world, std::wstring login, std::wstring pass, curl_accounts & tmp){
    std::unordered_map <int, std::vector<curl_accounts> > &t = curl_accountsdata; //world
    std::vector<curl_accounts> &b = t[world];
    std::vector<curl_accounts>::iterator & it = std::find_if(b.begin(), b.end(), [login, pass](curl_accounts& s) { return (s.name == login && s.pass == pass); });
    if (it != b.end()){
        tmp = *it;
    }
}
```

And `curl_accounts` is `struct`.

Now when I edit some value in the `struct` in one place, and try to check it in second place it not the same.

So could you fix my function?

**EDIT::**

```
curl_accounts tmp,tmp2;
program_data::getInstance().find_curlAccountdata(server, login, pass, tmp);
tmp.logged = true;
std::cout << "TMP LOGGED: "<< tmp.logged<<std::endl; // return true
program_data::getInstance().find_curlAccountdata(server, login, pass, tmp2);
std::cout << "TMP 2 LOGGED: " << tmp2.logged << std::endl; // return false
std::cout << "sth";
```

Comment: The references to items stored in the vector may invalidate as soon the original vector is changed.

Comment: So maybe i should use pointer?

Comment: Pointers and references are the same thing (under the hood) and therefore have the same invalidation rules. If (and ONLY if) you are sure to not do any invalidating operations, you are fine with either.

Comment: This doesn't "return" a reference at all. It *assigns* through the reference provided as `tmp`. Once initialized (which is required) you cannot change a reference, only what it *references*. (You can, of course, create a "dangling" reference if you set yourself to it).

Comment: You can't create a non-`const` reference to an rvalue (`it`), this code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @user657267 doesn't MS's "compiler" support that nonsense?

Comment: @user657267 He's probably using MSVC. tl;dr: it's an error, but MSVC allows it to be compiled without a diagnostic.

Comment: @WhozCraig @remyabel I had no idea, what an interesting bug `^H^H^H` feature.

Comment: Yes i'm using MSVC, so i have to rebuild my function?

Comment: @ThomasBanderas I think time [with this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c?rq=1) may help. No, you don't have to change too much, but `it` shouldn't be a reference. It should be just an iterator.

Answer (score -1):

You need a reference to a pointer. Try changing your signature to use `curl_accounts *& tmp`, instead of `curl_accounts &tmp`.

Comment: You can't have a pointer to a reference. You *can* have a reference to a pointer (which your syntax shows, but your opening sentence contradicts).

Comment: you're right, edited to reflect my intent. the signature is still right, while the comment's wrong.